# Find Position of Last Found Value in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, find, formula

I have a table with columns having different possible values (Text). I would like to find the position in the array of the last time a specified value was found (with a formula, no vba).

For example

```
A1     B1     C1     D1    E1    F1
Warm   Cold   Warm   Cool  Warm  Cold
```

I want to find the position of last time "Cold" was found from A1:F1, which would be "6" in the example given.

Thank you in advance

J.T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the **Array Formula**:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:Z1="Cold",COLUMN(A1:Z1)))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i needed.